# Bootstrap list-group-items flush with list-group container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is nitpicky; I'm working in Bootstrap with a fixed-sized list-group. When it starts, it has a nice outline/bottom border, but when I scroll the list, I lose it. I've tried breaking the top list-group-item from the rest of the group using a `<p>`, but I'm not satisfied with how that looks either.

[image: The nice-looking space between list-group and list-group-item]
Above: The nice-looking space between list-group and list-group-item

[image: When the two elements are flush, the bottom outline of the list-group-item above goes away]
When the two elements are flush, the bottom outline of the list-group-item above goes away

Comment: Use `margin` for a try

Comment: If you posted some code we would have insight as to what you have tried and your positioning. By the picture it appears that your scroll is overlapping the header. Could this problem be solved with giving the header a higher z-index? Would love to tell you but there is no code here to work with.

Comment: The z-index nailed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see the top element has position set to fixed. It looks like you need to apply margin (or margin-bottom) to the top element as it looks like it has a negative margin of -1px which would could be a reason as to why that border disappears.

Comment: Setting the z-index also worked. Changing the margin-bottom answer seems the simpler of the two solutions.